# Android How to Fail an espresso test

Tags: android, junit, automated-tests, android-espresso

Is there an elegant way to fail an espresso test. For example, the network isn't present dialog appears, how do I stop tests in such a case and fail.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the UI tests in an isolation (without Network data) or mock a server using Mockito.